# Creating a Login Form for Multiple Sites

Tags: javascript, html, login-script, whmcs

Our web-designer just finished up our site, and it has an HTML Form with Text Inputs for Username/Password, and a Drop-Down box so they can choose where they are logging in. Since HTML doesn't have anything that will work with this I don't believe, what would be the best way to do it?

I am assuming Javascript, but I have never used it before, and really have no idea what to even search for to apply it in this case.

Current Form Code:

```
<form>
    <input class="binput" name="username" style="margin-left: 40px;" value="Username">
    <input class="binput" name="password" value="Password">
        <select class="binput" style="margin-left: 40px; width: 130px;">
            <option>Billing Panel</option>
            <option>Voice Panel</option>
            <option>Game Panel</option>
        </select>

    <input type="submit" class="blogin" value="Log In">
</form>
```

Panel 1 Login Integration Example:

```
<form method="post" action="http://www.yourdomain.com/whmcs/dologin.php">
Email Address: <input type="text" name="username" size="50">
Password: <input type="password" name="password" size="20">
<input type="submit" value="Login">
</form>
```

Panel 2 Login Integration Example:

```
<form method="POST" action="http://demo.tcadmin.com/templates/default/login.aspx">
  <table border="0" id="table1"><br />
    <tr><td>User:</td><td><input type="text" name="USERID" size="20"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Password:</td><td><input type="password" name="PASSWORD" size="20"></td></tr>
  </table>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="B1"><input type="reset" value="Reset">
</form>
```

Comment: Are you wanting to submit the form to the site selected in the select?

Comment: Sidenote: This is very bad practice. You should NEVER send a or store a password in cleartext, but instead calculate a password hash in js, and then compare on the server if the submitted hash matches your stored password hash. From your sample it looks like a plain form-sumbit.

Comment: @natedavisolds - That is correct

Comment: @iHaveacomputer - I haven't added a mask for password yet, but your right, a password hash would be a good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html  >
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Title </title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="POST" action="" name="frmLogin" id="frmLogin" onSubmit="return   sbmt();">
    <input class="binput" name="username" style="margin-left: 40px;" value="Username" id="usr">
    <input class="binput" name="password" value="Password" type="password" id="pwd">
        <select class="binput" style="margin-left: 40px; width: 130px;" onchange="changeAction(this);" name="loginSite" id="loginSite">
            <option value="0" Selected >Select One</option> 
        <option value="1">Billing Panel</option>
            <option value="2">Voice Panel</option>
            <option value="3">Yahoo! Mail</option>
        </select>

    <input type="submit" class="blogin" value="Log In">
</form>
<script language="">
//Every element in LoginInfo is array of informations about one site!
var LoginInfo= new Array(
                new Array("usr","pwd",""),
                new Array("usr","pwd","http://www.yourdomain.com/whmcs/dologin.php"),
                new Array("username","password","http://demo.tcadmin.com/templates/default/login.aspx"),
                new Array("usrname","pass","https://login.yahoo.com/config/login_verify2?&.src=ym"));

function changeAction(s){

    var loginSite = s.value;
    document.getElementById('usr').name=LoginInfo[loginSite][0];
    document.getElementById('pwd').name=LoginInfo[loginSite][1];
    document.getElementById('frmLogin').action=LoginInfo[loginSite][2];

}

function sbmt(){


    var user = document.getElementById('usr');
    if(!user.value || user.value=="Username"){
        return false;
    }
    var pwd = document.getElementById('pwd');
    if(!pwd.value || pwd.value=="Password"){
        return false;
    }

    var site =document.getElementById('loginSite');
    if(  site.value=="0"){
        return false;
    }
        return true;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I edited the code!
I hope this one solve your problem:)

Comment: This is working perfectly! Thank you so much. My only question is that depending on what site they login to, the name property of the username input is different. Can this be changed via javascript?

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't use tables for layout, use CSS
2. Swap the CSS file for different sites, keeps the same HTML
3. Look for existing examples:
   https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=two-columns+forms
4. What exactly are you asking for?

Comment: How does this have anything to do with the question? The designer didn't use tables for layout, he used CSS.

Comment: Sorry Brett, but your "designer" doesn't have a clue how modern coding practices work.

Comment: You do realize the second two code snippets are "examples" from the various wiki sites on how to integrate their logins, as I mentioned in the original post right?

Comment: Some of these examples must be quite out of date. I also have a reputation of close to 18,000 so perhaps you should consider that I'm not being trite, but trying to offer some valid advice that may actually help.

Answer (score 0):

So, you'll need to change the `action` attribute of the form based on the selected value.

1. Include jQuery script (see jquery.com)
2. Add id to form

   ```
   <form id="login_form" action="put_the_first_url_here">
   ```
3. Add id to select

   ```
   <select id="login_into_url" class="binput" style="margin-left: 40px; width: 130px;">
   ```
4. Add the urls to the option's value.

   ```
   <option value="http://demo.tcadmin.com/templates/default/login.aspx">TCADMIN</option>
   ```
5. Add this script to bottom

   ```
   $(function() {     
        $('#login_into_url').change(function() {
            var url = $(this).val();
            $('#login_form').attr('action', url);
        });
    });
   ```

No way to test this now, but it should work.